# Convert datetime to utc format

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a datetime in string format with the specific time zone, but I cannot figure out to convert it into UTC format so as I could send it to the server backend and there it could be saved  to the database.

String obtained after date and time picker: "30-9-2016 15:10 Asia/Kolkata"
Need to convert it to UTC format

Answer (score 2):

Try to use joda http://www.joda.org/joda-time/.

This snippet results in "2016-09-30T09:40:00.000Z"

```
public String convert(String timeStamp) {
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-M-yyyy HH:mm ZZZ");
    DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(timeStamp);
    return dt.toInstant().toString();
}
```

Comment: I also need to deal with the GMT fomrat

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Joda-Time cannot parse identifiers like "Asia/Kolkata".

Comment: In my implementation it works, see this table http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html

Comment: Have now tested it myself. You are right. JodaTime can parse the identifier. The parsing limitation is only valid for tz names. So +1.

Answer (score 0):

You may use 'currentDate.utc().format()' for converting date into UTC.

Answer (score 0):

The class [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) seems to lack an option to parse time zone identifiers like "Asia/Kolkata" (neither a zone name nor an offset). There is no pattern symbol VV representing exact this kind of tz information.

If you insist on using `SimpleDateFormat` you could circumvent this limitation by using string preprocessing like:

```
input = input.replace("Asia/Kolkata", "GMT+05:30");
// and then use pattern symbol "z" or "Z"
```

The main disadvantage is: You make hardwired assumptions about the concrete tz identifier used in your input.

However, there are at least three other libraries which are capable of parsing the identifier "Asia/Kolkata" or similar using the pattern symbol "VV".

a) [ThreetenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) - an android adaptation of the backport of java.time-package in Java-8

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-yyyy HH:mm VV");
Instant instant = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, dtf).toInstant();
java.util.Date jud = new java.util.Date(instant.toEpochMilli());
```

b) [Joda-Time-Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android)

see the answer of @sven4all

c) my library [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A)

```
ChronoFormatter<Moment> f =
  ChronoFormatter.ofMomentPattern(
    "d-M-yyyy HH:mm VV", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT, ZonalOffset.UTC);
Moment moment = f.parse(input);
java.util.Date jud = TemporalType.JAVA_UTIL_DATE.from(moment);
```

What so ever, for storing in a database, you will probably need different conversions for example to the type `java.sql.Timestamp`.